# How to get started with yeoman and three.js?

Tags: node.js, three.js, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I installed three.js with `bower install threejs`.

Then after this I wish to have three.js in my page, so my app.js file starts with:

```
define(["jquery", "three"], function() {
  "use strict";
```

However when my page loads the Chrome console shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:9000/scripts/three.js
Uncaught Error: Script error
```

Well, shouldn't it be looking in components like it does for jQuery?

Basically how can I get started with yeoman and installing three.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is as follows.

The app.js file needs to refer to "three" as above and this refers to the file main.js which has the following.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: '../components/jquery/jquery',
        three: '../components/threejs/build/three'
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jquery'
        }
    }
});
```

The key here is the three which points where threejs three.js file is located.